# Show Kibana data table aggregations by columns instead of row

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-4

Using Kibana 4.4.1, I seem to be only able to create data table sub-bucket aggregations visualized as rows:

[image: Data table aggregation example]

Is there a way to display the aggregation as columns instead?

```
Invitation time              CampaignType:Sms   CampaignType:Email
Feb 19th 2016 15:45:00.000   3,185              8
Feb 23rd 2016 17:15:00.000   2,229              11
Feb 24th 2016 15:45:00.000   16,523             38
```

Answer (score 0):

There are ways to do it.
You may need to filter the columns based on sms and email before doing the visualization , then you may get the appropriate result.

Or with the result that you have , you can export it as Raw or formatted and then allign them according to your needs in Excel.